# Using helper class for boolean button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, boolean, helper

My button is as follows

```
<% if user.active == true  %>
        <%= button_to "Block", user_path(id: user.id, active: false), class: 'btn btn-outline-dark',  method:  :patch %>
        <%else%>
        <%= button_to "Unblock", user_path(id: user.id, active: true), class: 'btn btn-outline-dark',  method: :patch %>
        <%end%>
```

I need to have helper class for the above view code instead of repeating the button twice. Can anyone help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can just provide the logic inside `button_to` helper:

```
<%= button_to (user.active ? "Block" : "Unblock"), user_path(id: user.id, active: !user.active), class: 'btn btn-outline-dark',  method:  :patch %>
```

Thus, if you still think it's verbose, you can move `(user.active ? "Block" : "Unblock")` logic into a helper of decorator.

Answer (score 0):

In helpers:

```
def block_button(is_active)
  button_to is_active ? 'Block' : 'Unblock', user_path(id: user.id, active: !is_active), class: 'btn btn-outline-dark',  method:  :patch
end
```

In template

```
<%= block_button(user.active) %>
```